# I am not able to pass the values of one function to another function in java. How can I do it correctly ?

Tags: java, arrays, string

This is a code that I am working upon.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;    
public class Program {      
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      char[] a = new char[] {'0','1'};
      possibleStrings(3, a,"");
      char[] b = new char[] {'|','&'};
      possibleStrings(2, b,"");          
      result(a,b);   }

  public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr) {    
      if(curr.length() == maxLength) {
          System.out.print(curr);
          System.out.println();         
      } else {
          for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
              String oldCurr = curr;
              curr += alphabet[i];
              possibleStrings(maxLength,alphabet,curr);
              curr = oldCurr;
          }}}

  public static void result(char[] arrayA,char[] arrayB) {     
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while( i < arrayA.length && i < arrayB.length){
        sb.append(arrayA[i]).append(arrayB[i]);
        ++i;
        }
        for(int j = i; j < arrayA.length; ++j){
            sb.append(arrayA[j]);
        }
        for(int j = i; j < arrayB.length; ++j){
            sb.append(arrayB[j]);
        }            
        System.out.println("o/p="+sb.toString()); 
  }}
```

From main function I am passing the values to the possibleStrings and I am trying to collect the strings generated here back to the main function for both the same set of input i.e. `possibleStrings(3, a,"");` and `possibleStrings(2, b,"");` and then pass the strings a and b to the `result` function.

In result function I am trying to append the character strings character by character and obtain a combination of the output obtained in the above strings.

But the output that I am getting is wrong. I dont know where I am going wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: so: what exactly is the problem? the output or passing parameters? and what is the error?

Comment: here the output is comming as 0|1& and I need output like 0|0|0 to 0&0&0, 0|0|1 to 0&0&1........upto 1|1|1 to 1&1&1.

Comment: @Logan my question here is different Here I want to pass 2 different values to function possibleStrings and then want to retrive back the answers differently so that I can pass them in the function result.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct here is a mistake while passing the data to function : `possibleStrings(2, b,"");`
Replace it by :  `possibleStrings(2,'b',"");` since it was a character i think it should be in single quote.

Comment: No, the method takes an _array_ of char, not just a single char. The variable `b` is already an array of char and that is the intended actual argument. Not the single character `'b'`.